# MySQL | Easiest way to select data with a column on a certain day

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table with the following structure

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time  | int(19)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`time` being set to a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.

If I wanted to count the amount of values with a certain name, with a time value inside a day, would it be wise to change my table & application to use `DATETIME` type, or is there an easy way I could select different values for the day, and do this for multiple days & names.

I am using the `PDO` extension of `PHP` to query the database, and I am currently using the following code to create the query.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test` WHERE `name`='name' AND `time` > :time1First AND `time` < :time1Second) AS `time1`, ...");
```

I will be happy to try and clarify anything that is not understood from this post. It seemed clear to me, but that is probably just because I was the one who wrote it.

Comment: SO what is the problem here?

Comment: Just wondering if there is a better way to store the data / query it, or my current way is fine.

Comment: @Matthew MySQL has a special TIMESTAMP type. Why did you use int?

Comment: Not that relevant, but I myself never needed more than int(10), especially when dealing with unix timestamp, and I'm working on very big databases. So, regardless of your issue, consider changing the type. Your DB server will thank you :)

Comment: Is the `TIMESTAMP` datatype easy to use with PHP? I have been using `int` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` because of how easy it is to compare with PHP's `time()`.

Comment: @Matthew Working with TIMESTAMP is the same as working with int. But I recommend you to use DATETIME. It would make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

In my honest opinion, I would use a datetime column data type. They are easier to treat specially when doing queries like yours.

BTW, your query seems correct, but you'll need to enter an int representing the UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Regards,
Xavi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Xavier.
How would I go about using datetime with PHP? Can I format using `date()` ?

Comment: You are welcome Matthew. Yes, you can use something like date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). Regards.

Answer (score 0):

With GROUP BY you can count all times for every name. Try this

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as time1
  FROM test
 WHERE name = 'name' 
   AND time BETWEEN :time1First AND  :time1Second
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY name;
```